# How to use \Q \E to escape-literalize unicode chars with DOTALL?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code that regex's the specified input resulting in the following output below.  However, the unicode character is causing an exception thrown on m.find(). If you remove the unicode char before "Unicode" in the text everything works fine.

So, I tried decorating my regex to escape/literaize the any unicode chars with \Q \E (not sure if this is the correct approach or if I'm doing it correctly).  However, it prevents the exception but now it doesn't match on m.find().

How do I escape this unicode (and any unicode char) properly?

```
        String text = "Hi\n\nyo keep this here\n\nUnicode b4 keep all from here\n\nyo\ncut me:\n\nThis should be deleted";
        Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\Q(.+?)\\nyo(?:(?!cut me:|\\nyo).)*cut me:\\E",
                Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            text = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(text);
        }
```

Output:

> Hi
>
> yo keep this here
>
> Unicode b4 keep all from here

Comment: I like that new regex flag... `DO IT ALL` :)

Comment: OK, I'm now able to replicate the exception.  This appears to be a bug in the Java runtime.

Comment: You should look into Unicode properties defined in the `Pattern` javadoc, there is probably one which can help you

Comment: @ajb code points outside the BMP are not a problem in Java. Have a look at `Character.toChars()`. Java will use two chars for these, and represent such a code point as UTF-16 does, with a surrogate pair

Comment: @fge Yes, thanks.  I did figure that out just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer said, `\Q` and `\E` cause all of the characters in your regex to be interpreted as quoted characters that match themselves.

The answer is to upgrade to Java 8.  The bug appears to be fixed.

Here is a program written with all-ASCII characters that duplicates the behavior:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] special = Character.toChars(0x1F4F1);
        String text = "Hi\n\nyo keep this here\n\n" + new String(special) + "Unicode b4 keep all from here\n\nyo\ncut me:\n\nThis should be deleted";
        Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^(.+?)\\nyo(?:(?!cut me:|\\nyo).)*cut me:",
                Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
        if (m.find()) {
            text = m.group(1);
            System.out.println(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling and running this using Java 7 results in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Pattern.java:3867)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4360)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:4354)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:4304)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Slice.match(Pattern.java:3870)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4615)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match1(Pattern.java:4185)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:4134)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4556)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Begin.match(Pattern.java:3472)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.search(Matcher.java:1199)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.find(Matcher.java:592)
    at Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

With Java 8:

```
Hi

yo keep this here

?Unicode b4 keep all from here
```

(My system can't output the special character properly.)

Comment: thx for the deep dive. is there any way that I can some how escape the chars do the regex then unescape to return the text?  I have tried escape/unescape but it causes the regex not to match.  so that workaround seems like its out.

Comment: @JaJ You definitely don't want to escape the characters that are important to your pattern match.  I suspect escaping things isn't a solution.  I started trying a few things to get a handle on what regex features contribute to the problem, and I think your use of `\n` in the pattern might trigger it, but I'm not sure, and I really don't have time to try too many other things.  You might have to split your source string up by `\n`.  Other than that, I'm afraid you'll just have to experiment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\Q` and `\E` will actually change the behavior of your regex: as you wrote it, it's going to match LITERALLY that sequence:

```
(.+?)\\nyo(?:(?!cut me:|\\nyo).)*cut me:
```

That is, it's LITERALLY trying to find a `parenthesis`, followed by a litteral `dot`, followed a literal `+`, and so on...

---

To clarify a little:

```
final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\Q(.+?)\\nyo(?:(?!cut me:|\\nyo).)*cut me:\\E", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher("(.+?)\\nyo(?:(?!cut me:|\\nyo).)*cut me:");
System.out.println(m.match());   // true
```

Comment: ah, makes sense. looks like that won't work for me. thanks for the very clear summary.